# How to remove item from ArrayList if condition in other ArrayList is true

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, jtable, illegalstateexception

I have a JTable with three columns, each of which is filled with an array made from an ArrayList. I am trying to make a search system, where the user will search for a value in the first column, and the rows of the JTable will filter out, so that only the rows that contain the specified String from the search box show up on the table after a button is pressed. On another table, this worked by filtering the ArrayList used using this loop:

```
String s = searchBar.getText();
ArrayList<String> fn = new ArrayList<>();
fn.addAll(names); //names is the arraylist that contains all the values that will be filtered
for(Iterator<String> it = fn.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    if (!it.next().contains(s)) {
        it.remove();
    }
```

This code works to filter out the array, but what I am trying to do is filter 3 ArrayLists based on only if one of the ArrayLists does not contain the s String.
I tried doing this:

```
String s = searchBar.getText();
ArrayList<String> fn = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> fp = new ArrayList<>();
fn.addAll(names); //names is the arraylist that contains all the values that will be filtered
fp.addAll(numbers)//one of the other arraylists that I want to filter
for(Iterator<String> it = fn.iterator(), itp = fp.iterator(); it.hasNext() && itp.hasNext(); ) {
    if (!it.next().contains(s)) {
        itp.remove();
        it.remove();
    }
```

When I run this code I get a Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException on the line where I write "itp.remove();".
Is there a way I can remove from both the arrays based on only one of them?

Comment: Add `itp.next()` in the loop as well.

Comment: Youcan't iterate and remove elements. Its not synchronized. But you can remove while loop since to start of list

Comment: If I were you I'd take an OOP approach and instead of having three parallel `List`'s, construct an object to hold the info and just have a list of that

Comment: @GBlodgett The reason I have it like that is becauss the data is being taken from an sql database, and really I didnt know any other way to do it lol

Comment: @Dred Im sorry, I didnt quite understand you

Comment: Read the second method carefullyhttps://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-element-arraylist-java/amp/. Also, you can insert into your 1 list every object from each of your table, why not?

Comment: @Dred I still get the same error, I think it's because I am using 2 iterators in the same loop, as when I try with only 1 of the Iterators it works fine

Comment: Sorry, Im from Phone and cant write correct code, but try to loop in inner loop like for() {for() {}}

Comment: @Dred I tried this earlier and I still got the same exception. Thank you though, the article you linked really helped

Comment: @Dred I searched a bit on how to do this with streams, which would be good for multithreading, but given that my tables are really small (not even 50 rows) I think it won't be really necessary right now, and the code is still quite bothersome to me as just now I am starting to learn and use streams. But in this particular case, I think the for loop will do fine.

Comment: I didn't check if fn and fp are of same size because, the ArrayLists that they are copying are already checked to be of same size in another part of the class so I kinda just assumed fn and fp would always be the same size and went straight to the delete.

Comment: @JoeyJohnJo anyway, I'm glad to know you fix thar:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm happy that you fix your exception. Anyway, when I said about back iteration I meant something like that

Firstly, Some of check like

```
 if(fn.size()==fp.size()){
   // and after that go to delete. 
  for (int i=fn.size(); i>0;i--) { 
      if (fn.contains(s)) {
      fn.remove(i);
      fp.remove(i);
  } }}
```

Anyway, your and my method isn't good for multithreading, because ArrayList doesnt't concurrent object also it's remove method

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to fix it by using the remove method from the ArrayList instead of the remove method from the Iterator. I know this isn't the recommended way of doing it, but it seems to not have brought any negatives with it, so I will keep it for now.
The code I used is:

```
int i = 0;
for (Iterator<String> it = fn.iterator(); it.hasNext(); i++) {
    if (!it.next().contains(s)) {
        it.remove(); //Iterator's remove
        fp.remove(i);// ArrayList's remove which avoids the error
    }
}
```

Thank you to all who helped